# How to know what exact commands are run when I hit the play button on the VStudio 2010 IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am relatively new to Visual Studio, and I would like to know what's exactly happening when I hit the play button of the IDE to build the project. Is there someway to know what commands are executed on the background?

When I open the Output Window, I just get to see the following.

```
------ Build started: Project: ZXing.Net.Mobile.MonoForAndroid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

ZXing.Net.Mobile.MonoForAndroid -> C:\Users\avi\Desktop\APC-mono\ZXing.Net.Mobile\bin\Debug\ZXing.Mobile.dll

========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In the Options dialog (from `Tools | Options...`)
- in the tree on the left choose `Projects and Solutions | Build and Run`
- on the right, under `MSBuild project build output verbosity`, choose (say) `Normal`

Now when you build, the build output will have more detail. Note that `Detailed` is probably more detailed than you need, and `Diagnostic` is almost certainly more detailed than you need.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

By clicking the play button, you start debugging the program. All programs starts where Main() is found.

Comment: This is only part of the answer.

Comment: I'm not a Visual Studio developer but usually a play button represents 'run' the program instead of 'debug'